# Is it possible to get the latest version in TFS using some console client?

Tags: tfs, console-application, getlatest

Currently I found two ways to get the latest version - in Visual Studio using Team Explorer and in Windows Explorer using TFS Power Tools Shell Extensions.

Because our TFS server is located vary far from developers working with it is very slow and very often hangs on an application (VS/Explorer). So I want to run Get in console to minimize the load on OS during the oepration.

It seems that both tf.exe and tfpt.exe doesn't contain anything like Get.

Are there anything else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TF.exe does have a get command. The following is the output of `TF.exe get -?`

```
TF - Team Foundation Version Control Tool, Version 10.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Retrieves a read-only copy of a file from Team Foundation Server to the local
workspace and creates folders on disk to contain it.

tf get itemspec [/version:versionspec] [/all] [/overwrite] [/force] [/preview]
       [/recursive] [/remap] [/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]]

Versionspec:
    Date/Time         D"any .Net Framework-supported format"
                      or any of the date formats of the local machine
    Changeset number  Cnnnnnn
    Label             Llabelname
    Latest version    T
    Workspace         Wworkspacename;workspaceowner
```

Now you don't mention a specific version, but I am pretty sure it has been in TF.exe since first release.

To get latest version of a solution directory, simply navigate to the mapped directory on the command line, and execute:

```
tf.exe get * -recursive
```

Comment: Thanks! I was inattentive examining `tf | more`